# Batch script removing directory in loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have to removing directory which are created automatically. Every directory has name with this same prefix and number of build. Script should taking the parameter and remove whole directory contains number less than parameter or equal. I have written something like that but it doesnt work. My script remove just first directory.

```
@echo Off
G:
cd G:\UAT

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /D %%i in (buildnr_*) do (
set dirName=%%i
set dirNumber=!dirName:~8,5!
    if !dirNumber! LEQ %1 (
        rimraf buildnr_!dirNumber!
        echo "----------------buildnr_!dirNumber! has been removed.----------------"
    )
)
```

Comment: What is the content of the input argument `%1`, also what happens when you use the built-in cmd.exe command `RD /S/Q`?

Comment: %1 takes the number contains in directory name and should remove whole directories less and include this number. I cant use rmdir or RD because in this direcotries is node.js and widnows cant remove this long path.

Comment: It was obvious what type of information was passed as `%1`, what I asked for was its content!

Comment: What "parameter"? What "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

A method such as this may work for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If "%~1"=="" Exit /B
CD /D "G:\UAT" 2>Nul || Exit /B
RD "empty" 2>Nul
MD "empty"
For /D %%A In ("buildnr_*") Do (
    Set "bn=%%A"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If !bn:~-5! LEq %~1 (
        RoboCopy /MIR "empty" "%%A" >Nul 2>&1
        RD "%%A" && (
            Echo "--------------- %%A has been removed. ---------------"
        )
    )
    EndLocal
)
RD "empty"
```

I have included a check that an input argument, `%1`, was passed to the script, it is important, and your responsibility to verify its content is the correct format/length/type of string, *(with special regard to the `LEq` condition)*.